# ffmpeg - Text fontcolor is changed (faded) because of alpha(I think). Is there any possibility to avoid this behavior?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using following command

```
    ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/input.mp4 -filter_complex  "color=black:100x100[c];\
[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv]; \
[ct]setsar=1,split=1[t1]; \
[t1]drawtext=text='Test Text 1':fontsize=36:fontcolor=#13348b\
,split[text1][alpha1]; \
[text1][alpha1]alphamerge,rotate=30:ow=rotw(30)\
:oh=roth(30):c=black@0[txta1]; \
[mv][txta1]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(30))+500':\
y='min(0,W*sin(30))+350':shortest=1" \
~/Desktop/result.mp4 -y
```

I think alpha is the problem, but I don't know how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're using the text layer as alpha as well, and since the text isn't pure white, it won't be fully opaque. When I originally posted the command in your Q, the drawtext filter couldn't draw text on a transparent canvas and retain the transparency. That has since been rectified. So, the command is simpler now.

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/input.mp4 -filter_complex  \
          "color=black@0:100x100,format=yuva444p[c]; \
           [c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv]; \
           [ct]setsar=1,drawtext=text='Test Text 1':fontsize=36:fontcolor=#13348b, \
               rotate=30:ow=rotw(30):oh=roth(30):c=black@0[txta1]; \
           [mv][txta1]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(30))+500':\y='min(0,W*sin(30))+350':shortest=1" \
       ~/Desktop/result.mp4 -y
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can I draw multiple texts using only one overlay(and change x and y for each of them)?

Comment: Yes, do them in sequence after the first drawtext and before the rotate.